# obtener propiedad label de un json con getJSON y each

Tags: jquery, json

Estoy queriendo obtener el item label de este json y no puedo la lista sale vacía o undefined, creo que es un array mulitidimencional y falta ingresar a un nivel mas, no puedo construir el código correcto es lo que tengo necesito ayuda con esto gracias.

```
JSON:
{
  "entities": {
    "categories": [
      {
        "horror": {
          "id": 1,
          "label": "Terror"
        },
        "comedy": {
          "id": 2,
          "label": "Comedia"
        },
        "drama": {
          "id": 3,
          "label": "Drama"
        }
      }
    ]
}

// SCRIPT

$(document).ready( function() {
 $.getJSON("/books-schema.json",
        function(data){
          $.each(data.entities.categories, function(i,item){
            $("<li>").html(item.label).appendTo("#categoria");
          });
        });
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro del objeto `entities` existe una propiedad llamada `categories` de tipo array (`[]`); **dicho array contiene solamente un elemento** (objeto) con tres propiedades: "horror", "comedy" y "drama". Para que tu código funcione (usando un objeto JSON tal como se ilustra), tienes que cambiar la función *callback* dentro de la instrucción `.getJSON` de la siguiente manera:

```js
function(data) {
  $.each(data.entities.categories[0], function(i, item) {
    $("<li>").html(item.label).appendTo("#categoria");
  });
});
```

De esta manera la instrucción `$.each` recorrerá **cada elemento dentro del primer y único elemento** (0) del array `categories`, retornando la lista interna como buscas.

---

**NOTA:** Si tienes acceso al código de la aplicación o servicio que genera dicho JSON, podrías cambiar su estructura para que se genere de la siguiente manera y tu código funcione tal como lo tienes:

```
{
  "entities": {
    "categories": {
      "horror": {
        "id": 1,
        "label": "Terror"
      },
      "comedy": {
        "id": 2,
        "label": "Comedia"
      },
      "drama": {
        "id": 3,
        "label": "Drama"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Con dicho esquema `categories` se convierte en un objeto con las propiedades individuales "horror", "comedy" y "drama" y puede ser accedido directamente usando `data.entities.categories`. [Aquí](https://jsbin.com/gupoxikiga/1/edit?js,console) puedes ver el ejemplo de esto.

Comment: Muchas Gracias funciono perfectamente, había intentado colocando el [0] pero no me funcionaba a lo mejor no esta bien de igual forma ya lo resolví gracias por todo.

Answer (score 0):

sigo con ese tema ahora quiero obtner los id de ese array en los li generados estoy usando esta estructura obtengo el id pero el ultimo el id 3 se repite en todos, dame una mano como puedo obtener el id respectivo por cada label.
Muchas Gracias.

SOLUCION:

```
$.each(data.entities.categories[0], function(i, item) {
  $('#categoria').append($('<li>').attr('id', item.id).html(item.label));
```

});

```
<ul id="categoria">
<li id="1">Terror</li>
<li id="2">Comedia</li>
<li id="3">Drama</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: ¿Estás agregando las dos instrucciones dentro del bloque de la función `each` (o sea dentro de las llaves)? Tal vez está quedando "fuera" la línea donde asignas el atributo `id` y eso causa que no se asigne _cada vez_, sino después de todo el ciclo.

Comment: si esta dentro igual no lo logro 
$.each(data.entities.categories[0], function(i, item) {
        $("<li>").html(item.label).appendTo("#categoria");
         $("li").attr('id', item.id);
  });

Comment: ya lo corregí arriba así me queda lo pruebo pero me repite el id 3, no por cada label, que puede ser el problema. gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ya encontré la solución lo dejo por si a alguien le sirve;

$.each(data.entities.categories[0], function(i, item) {
      $('#categoria').append($('<li>').attr('id', item.id).html(item.label));
  });